# How do I avoid duplicate entries using merge()?

Tags: r, merge

Please forgive me if this sounds like a really dumb question, I just started getting back into coding.

I have 6 databases with 3 columns and 16 rows in each that I'm trying to analyze by using the merge() function. When using the merge function, the by.x and by.y arguments are being repeated 7 or 8 times, and I can't figure out why and how to fix it.
This is what it looks like:

```
mycob1 <- read.csv("MYCOB_1.csv")
mycob2 <- read.csv("MYCOB_2.csv")
mycob1 
Lot_210927       RFU        Ct
1           0    6.3588  9.164329
2           0    5.0394 11.350701
3           0    4.9946 37.334669
4           0    4.8604  8.168337
5           0    4.9032 37.306613
6           0    4.9502 22.176353
7           0    4.7858 23.713427
8           0    5.2778 10.496994
9           1 1021.8458 32.119668
10          1 1020.1998 31.500716
11          1 1065.8000 31.979674
12          1  988.0452 31.019754
13          1 1085.2206 31.557973
14          1 1072.8540 31.745491
15          1 1020.6496 31.218151
16          1  983.4106 31.981162
mycob2
   Lot_211020       RFU       Ct
1           0    0.6876 47.72087
2           0   40.1056 38.37418
3           0   97.0882 37.72917
4           0   10.3170 36.18236
5           0   67.3742 37.39050
6           0   10.2540 40.16776
7           0    6.9624 28.07575
8           0    9.5718 28.84626
9           0   13.0306 38.87375
10          1  860.3956 29.15746
11          1  884.9338 30.03665
12          1 1552.2462 27.90839
13          1  738.2328 29.22760
14          1 1419.6448 29.13627
15          1 1441.6212 29.35351
16          1  424.9774 31.56446
>
M1 <- merge(mycob1, mycob2, 
      by.x = "Lot_210927", 
      by.y = "Lot_211020", 
      all.x = TRUE, 
      all.y = FALSE)
Lot_210927     RFU.x      Ct.x     RFU.y     Ct.y
1            0    6.3588  9.164329    0.6876 47.72087
2            0    6.3588  9.164329   40.1056 38.37418
3            0    6.3588  9.164329   97.0882 37.72917
4            0    6.3588  9.164329   10.3170 36.18236
5            0    6.3588  9.164329   67.3742 37.39050
6            0    6.3588  9.164329   10.2540 40.16776
7            0    6.3588  9.164329    6.9624 28.07575
8            0    6.3588  9.164329    9.5718 28.84626
9            0    6.3588  9.164329   13.0306 38.87375
10           0    5.0394 11.350701    0.6876 47.72087
11           0    5.0394 11.350701   40.1056 38.37418
12           0    5.0394 11.350701   97.0882 37.72917
13           0    5.0394 11.350701   10.3170 36.18236
14           0    5.0394 11.350701   67.3742 37.39050
15           0    5.0394 11.350701   10.2540 40.16776
16           0    5.0394 11.350701    6.9624 28.07575
17           0    5.0394 11.350701    9.5718 28.84626
18           0    5.0394 11.350701   13.0306 38.87375
19           0    4.9946 37.334669    0.6876 47.72087
20           0    4.9946 37.334669   40.1056 38.37418
21           0    4.9946 37.334669   97.0882 37.72917
22           0    4.9946 37.334669   10.3170 36.18236
23           0    4.9946 37.334669   67.3742 37.39050
24           0    4.9946 37.334669   10.2540 40.16776
25           0    4.9946 37.334669    6.9624 28.07575
26           0    4.9946 37.334669    9.5718 28.84626
27           0    4.9946 37.334669   13.0306 38.87375
28           0    4.8604  8.168337    0.6876 47.72087
29           0    4.8604  8.168337   40.1056 38.37418
30           0    4.8604  8.168337   97.0882 37.72917
31           0    4.8604  8.168337   10.3170 36.18236
32           0    4.8604  8.168337   67.3742 37.39050
33           0    4.8604  8.168337   10.2540 40.16776
34           0    4.8604  8.168337    6.9624 28.07575
35           0    4.8604  8.168337    9.5718 28.84626
36           0    4.8604  8.168337   13.0306 38.87375
37           0    4.9032 37.306613    0.6876 47.72087
38           0    4.9032 37.306613   40.1056 38.37418
39           0    4.9032 37.306613   97.0882 37.72917
40           0    4.9032 37.306613   10.3170 36.18236
41           0    4.9032 37.306613   67.3742 37.39050
42           0    4.9032 37.306613   10.2540 40.16776
43           0    4.9032 37.306613    6.9624 28.07575
44           0    4.9032 37.306613    9.5718 28.84626
45           0    4.9032 37.306613   13.0306 38.87375
46           0    4.9502 22.176353    0.6876 47.72087
47           0    4.9502 22.176353   40.1056 38.37418
48           0    4.9502 22.176353   97.0882 37.72917
49           0    4.9502 22.176353   10.3170 36.18236
50           0    4.9502 22.176353   67.3742 37.39050
51           0    4.9502 22.176353   10.2540 40.16776
52           0    4.9502 22.176353    6.9624 28.07575
53           0    4.9502 22.176353    9.5718 28.84626
54           0    4.9502 22.176353   13.0306 38.87375
55           0    4.7858 23.713427    0.6876 47.72087
56           0    4.7858 23.713427   40.1056 38.37418
57           0    4.7858 23.713427   97.0882 37.72917
58           0    4.7858 23.713427   10.3170 36.18236
59           0    4.7858 23.713427   67.3742 37.39050
60           0    4.7858 23.713427   10.2540 40.16776
61           0    4.7858 23.713427    6.9624 28.07575
62           0    4.7858 23.713427    9.5718 28.84626
63           0    4.7858 23.713427   13.0306 38.87375
64           0    5.2778 10.496994    0.6876 47.72087
65           0    5.2778 10.496994   40.1056 38.37418
66           0    5.2778 10.496994   97.0882 37.72917
67           0    5.2778 10.496994   10.3170 36.18236
68           0    5.2778 10.496994   67.3742 37.39050
69           0    5.2778 10.496994   10.2540 40.16776
70           0    5.2778 10.496994    6.9624 28.07575
71           0    5.2778 10.496994    9.5718 28.84626
72           0    5.2778 10.496994   13.0306 38.87375
73           1 1021.8458 32.119668  860.3956 29.15746
74           1 1021.8458 32.119668  884.9338 30.03665
75           1 1021.8458 32.119668 1552.2462 27.90839
76           1 1021.8458 32.119668  738.2328 29.22760
77           1 1021.8458 32.119668 1419.6448 29.13627
78           1 1021.8458 32.119668 1441.6212 29.35351
79           1 1021.8458 32.119668  424.9774 31.56446
80           1 1020.1998 31.500716  860.3956 29.15746
81           1 1020.1998 31.500716  884.9338 30.03665
82           1 1020.1998 31.500716 1552.2462 27.90839
83           1 1020.1998 31.500716  738.2328 29.22760
84           1 1020.1998 31.500716 1419.6448 29.13627
85           1 1020.1998 31.500716 1441.6212 29.35351
86           1 1020.1998 31.500716  424.9774 31.56446
87           1 1065.8000 31.979674  860.3956 29.15746
88           1 1065.8000 31.979674  884.9338 30.03665
89           1 1065.8000 31.979674 1552.2462 27.90839
90           1 1065.8000 31.979674  738.2328 29.22760
91           1 1065.8000 31.979674 1419.6448 29.13627
92           1 1065.8000 31.979674 1441.6212 29.35351
93           1 1065.8000 31.979674  424.9774 31.56446
94           1  988.0452 31.019754  860.3956 29.15746
95           1  988.0452 31.019754  884.9338 30.03665
96           1  988.0452 31.019754 1552.2462 27.90839
97           1  988.0452 31.019754  738.2328 29.22760
98           1  988.0452 31.019754 1419.6448 29.13627
99           1  988.0452 31.019754 1441.6212 29.35351
100          1  988.0452 31.019754  424.9774 31.56446
101          1 1085.2206 31.557973  860.3956 29.15746
102          1 1085.2206 31.557973  884.9338 30.03665
103          1 1085.2206 31.557973 1552.2462 27.90839
104          1 1085.2206 31.557973  738.2328 29.22760
105          1 1085.2206 31.557973 1419.6448 29.13627
106          1 1085.2206 31.557973 1441.6212 29.35351
107          1 1085.2206 31.557973  424.9774 31.56446
108          1 1072.8540 31.745491  860.3956 29.15746
109          1 1072.8540 31.745491  884.9338 30.03665
110          1 1072.8540 31.745491 1552.2462 27.90839
111          1 1072.8540 31.745491  738.2328 29.22760
112          1 1072.8540 31.745491 1419.6448 29.13627
113          1 1072.8540 31.745491 1441.6212 29.35351
114          1 1072.8540 31.745491  424.9774 31.56446
115          1 1020.6496 31.218151  860.3956 29.15746
116          1 1020.6496 31.218151  884.9338 30.03665
117          1 1020.6496 31.218151 1552.2462 27.90839
118          1 1020.6496 31.218151  738.2328 29.22760
119          1 1020.6496 31.218151 1419.6448 29.13627
120          1 1020.6496 31.218151 1441.6212 29.35351
121          1 1020.6496 31.218151  424.9774 31.56446
122          1  983.4106 31.981162  860.3956 29.15746
123          1  983.4106 31.981162  884.9338 30.03665
124          1  983.4106 31.981162 1552.2462 27.90839
125          1  983.4106 31.981162  738.2328 29.22760
126          1  983.4106 31.981162 1419.6448 29.13627
127          1  983.4106 31.981162 1441.6212 29.35351
128          1  983.4106 31.981162  424.9774 31.56446
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: you actually do a cross product. every instance of 0 in a is merged to every instance of 0 in B and so on with the ones

Comment: What is the desired output? You have duplicate keys so a normal merge probably doesn't make sense. Maybe you just want `cbind()`?

Comment: Thanks, I got the cbind() function to work! Yea, I think the issue with merge() is that it gives me every possible combination of mycob1 and mycob2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
left_join(mycob1, mycob2, by.x = "Lot_210927", by.y = "Lot_211020")
```

A left join in R is a merge operation between two data frames where the merge returns all of the rows from one table (the left side) and any matching rows from the second table.

If you want other joins, see here: https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/join-in-r-merge-in-r/ for a good explanation of join options.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Left_join() isn't a function in RStudio though :/. I appreciate the link, it helped a lot!